# How to censor content on computer screen without affecting the original one

Tags: c++, windows

sorry for the weird question, but here is the scenario:

1. I'm developing a Windows application that tracks content on computer screen.

2. If something inappropriate appear on the screen, I will censored it ( black square maybe)

But I still want to capture what's happening under the black square to keep tracking, so my question is how to capture the screen output under the "black quare" without destroy the "black square" ?

 Sorry again for my English, hope I described it well enough for you guys to understand!

Update for more information: 
I'm doing it this way: I capture the screen, detect an inappropriate object ( b**bs for example), get its position, create a square box by using openGL and draw a black square at the given position. The point is, the next screen output ( pictured) will be censored with black square --> So I can't track what is happenning under the black square, so I can't decide whether to keep censoring or not

Comment: You will have to narrow this down. Can you show how you render the uncensored output? Is it an optoin to render the censored output to the screen, while rendering the uncensored output in the background without displaying. That seems to achieve what you want, though differently than you imagine how to achieve it. (I.e. I am implying that you might have an XY-problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm doing it this way:
I capture the screen, detect an inappropriate object ( b**bs for example), get its position, create a square box by using openGL and draw a black square at the given position. The point is, the next screen output ( pictured) will be censored with black square --> So I can't track what is happenning under the black square, so I can't decide whether to keep censoring or not.

Comment: So you are watching what other programs generate not what your own do? If I am right, [edit] this info into your question. In my opinion it gets more interesting that way, not easier though...

Comment: Another thing to clarify. You currently get one frame with inappropriates, then they get noticed and censored, right?

Comment: Ok, I will update the question. I'm watching whatever happen on the screen ( not specific programs) . Currently, I will capture screen continously, if inappropriate things appear on the screen, I censored it, and keep track of it ( I plan to use object tracking method from openCV), till it disappear, I will destroy the square box, so as I mentioned above, the next frame would contain the black square box --> No inappropriate content, all boxes are destroyed ---> inappropriate content appears again! I have no clue about the keywords for this scenario then :(

Comment: Probably **impossible in practice** (or you'll filter a lot of genuine useful content). See https://xkcd.com/1425/ ... (many years ago I worked in [POESIA](http://webilc.ilc.cnr.it/viewpage.php/sez=ricerca/id=61/vers=ing)...) your goal is unrealistic

Comment: Hi Basile, Thanks for your comment, what is the impossible in this scenario? I have detected the inappropriate objects successfully, just want to know how to seperate the censor box with the original screen

Comment: I leave you to explore. Worked in a team for several years on similiar goals. You'll need years of work to understand how hard it is. Good luck, and have fun. E.g. automatically detecting *reliably* nudity is not a solved problem... So cultural... In France, [L'origine du monde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Origine_du_monde) is considered visible by everyone, including minors...) and the museum showing it is visited by kids.

Comment: Thanks Basile then! You might want to check my result: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=91044ccb1f9e1346&id=91044CCB1F9E1346%21552&authkey=%21AEoarZcugIWjPh4 ( it might inappropriate to you) and i would apply this in the program: https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/ to keep track of the given position of the bounding boxes. Would you please tell me what is the impossible? Cause it's my capstone project so it would be possible :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any MicroSoft account (and don't want to). But really, enjoy your research project, it is technically very interesting; in France, that *Origine du Monde* painting is considered as art visible by everyone

Comment: Thank you Basile, You can just click on "No thanks, Continue to view". thanks again for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this reliably due to the DRM (Digital Rights Management) in Windows. If it would be so easy to grab pixels off the screen, it would be easy to grab entire movies.

That said, not all content is protected. In that case, just implement the black box as a separate window, on top of other windows. You can still grab the content of windows when they are behind other windows. Your current solution sounds like you're grabbing the on-screen composited result, and that indeed is a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you please help me with they keywords, I have no idea what keywords I should use to search about this ? or would you recommend me something like that!?

Comment: or should I just simply create a seperate windows ?

Comment: @MrStar1102: Yes, just create an ordinary window, but call `SetWindowPos(YourWindow, HWND_TOP, location, 0)` to put it on top.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give it a try!